# ElasticSearch: New user with admin privileges of an index unable to access it in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I want to create a user who has admin rights (search, read, write) access on `testIndex` index. For this, I created a role `testIndex_admin` (ref. kibana screenshot given below) and assigned the new user this role. 
[image]

However after the user logs in he only see an empty screen with a "Help us improve the Elastic Stack by providing basic feature usage statistics?" popup. On the browser console I found the following request being made which failed with 403 error.

Request URL: http://localhost:5601/api/saved_objects/_find?type=index-pattern&per_page=10000

```
{
    "message": "action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user [user01]: [security_exception] action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user [user01]",
    "statusCode": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden"
}
```

Also, I get the following "Advanced Setting Error" popup that appears (give below) [image]

ElasticSearch v6.3.2
Kibana v6.3.2

What can be done so that the user can access only his testIndex with all priviliges to it?

Answer (score 0):

The `kibana_user` role grants access to the resources that are required when using Kibana.
You need to grant that role, and whatever additional roles you require to get access to the data itself.

So, if you want the user to be able to use Kibana, then you need to give them the `kibana_user` role.

So for example my list of roles would appear something like this:
`testIndex_admin` `kibana_user`